# Facebook graph API likes request doesn't work anymore

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Last time I got the way to know how many users liked a photo with this way:

https://graph.facebook.com/161820597180936/likes?limit=1000

But I don't know why it doesn't work anymore.  Now it only returns 3 or 4 facebook users in the case they work very well before. It happened 2 days ago, so I guess facebook changed something in it's API. Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [a bug in the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/275104435865868), and should eventually be fixed by Facebook.

Facebook has pledged to provide [90 day notifications before making breaking changes to the API](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/change-policy/), so it is important to file bugs even if you assume that a change was intentional but there was no prior notification.

Comment: Thank you, I think I will file bugs and see

Comment: I got the solution here, I can get the right number of user who like photo but can't get who like this photo if this photo have more than 500 likes

Answer (score -1):

Now it comes back as a part of the Graph API data set.

Look at the page - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/ - for what the API header is, and then under the photos, it'll show you the data set that gets returned from the photo api request - (PHP example - https://graph.facebook.com/98423808305)

Hope that helps.

Comment: The "PHP example" you give has the exact same issue as the OP's Photo object - 800+ people have Liked the photo, but the Graph API is only showing 4 of them.

Comment: I'll see if I can hack out some code this next week to get that to work.  Are you using the latest SDK?

Comment: Yes, I am using the latest SDK

Comment: I've hit the same problem, and given the link up above about the bug, looks like it has to be solved by FB.  Good luck.